# Angular - extract directive's attributes values on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form that consists of a few known inputs and a few that are included from partials that I don't control but can expect to be correctly written. Simplified it looks like this:

```
<form ...>
  <input name="input1" type="hidden" value="1">
  <div class="from_partial" ng-controller="Controller">
    <!-- here goes first partial -->
    <button type="button" ng-click="check()">Check</button>
  </div>
  <div class="from_partial" ng-controller="Controller">
    <!-- here goes second partial -->
    <button type="button" ng-click="check()">Check</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Partial looks like this:

```
<div class="item">
  <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <input type="text" ng-model="age"/>
</div>
```

Now I need to somehow use those inputs in the Controller's `check()` function, separately for each partial. I don't know their names in advance. What's the best way to enumerate them? Is it possible to get them  (i.e. find out their names) while Angular is bootstraping and wiring particular models with their `$scope`?

In other words, I would like each `Controller` object to know the names of the inputs, for example `$scope.input_names` containing `{"name", "age"}`.

Comment: If the form had an "name" attribute you can get it's all models in `$scope.formName` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it's possible to define multiple directives with the same name and with this it becomes easy:

```
angular.module(app_name)
.controller("Controller", ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.input_names = [];
    ...
}])
.directive('ngModel', function() {
    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.input_names.push(attrs.ngModel);
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        priority: 100,
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: linker
    };
});
```

The original Angular directive is defined with priority 1 and will get executed first. Then the custom directive will insert names defined using `ng-model` attributes to `scope.input_names`. This ensures that each controller will only get names that are defined in the related partial. Everything else related to `ng-model` will work as usual.